How so I make a list of references using bibtex and with document class report?
I've seen similar questions but all of them used the article document class and when I've tried the same thing for mine - it didn't work, obviously. I know that it has to be like:
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{example1} example here
  \bibitem{example2} example2 here
\end{thebibliography}

And making the refernce by \cite{example1} in the text.
But it doesn't work if I use the report class which I need to use in my writing. So I'm wondering what should be changed or added and how.

Please clarify what "it didn't work" and "it doesn't work" consists of in your document. For sure, if I prefix \documentclass{report} \begin{document} \cite{example1} to your four-line code snippet and affix \end{document}, the resulting minimalist test document compiles without error or warning and the output is as expected.

@Mico well, I made a mistake in the primary question. I mean, it is working yet I'm getting an error "Command \cyrgup unavailable in encoding T2B." refering to the \begin{thebibliography} line and this is kinda strange.

The error Command \cyrgup unavailable in encoding T2B is caused by some part of the document that you don't show, so we can't help. Please come up with a small document that produces this error and then add it to your posting.

If using bibtex you do not write a \begin{thebibliography}{9} and a list of bibitem, the only purpose of bibtex is to write such an  enviornment for you.  The code you show would work in article or report and does not need bibtex at all.

The issue that gives rise to the "Command \cyrgup unavailable in encoding T2B" message is wholly unrelated to bibliography creation or the report document class. Please either rewrite your query from the ground up or post a new query.
